# VB macro to transfer data from one worksheet to another with changing filename

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA macro in Excel which opens both the source and targets files, copies the required data and closes the files. The target filename is always the same, but the source file is a new file every day with the date as part of the name. The name format is SB20200613.DBF. This is today's file 13 June. For all of 2020, the files will always be SB2020XXXX.DBF.

Here is the macro

```
Public Sub Copy_DBF_to_Workbook()

    Const cRootFolder   As String = "C:\Price\"        ' <<<<< change accordingly (without year!)

    Const cDestWorkBk   As String = "Prices.xlsx"

    Dim oWsSrc          As Worksheet
    Dim oWsDest         As Worksheet
    Dim raSrc           As Range
    Dim raDest          As Range
    Dim sPath           As String
    Dim sDBF            As String
    Dim sFName          As String
    Dim dtDate          As Date

    ' assign current date
    dtDate = Date

    ' assign yesterday's date
'    dtDate = Date - 1

    ' compose path for current year
    sPath = cRootFolder & Year(dtDate) & "\"

    ' compose file name
    sDBF = "SB" & Year(dtDate) & IIf(Len(Month(dtDate)) = 1, "0" & Month(dtDate), Month(dtDate)) & _
                                 IIf(Len(Day(dtDate)) = 1, "0" & Day(dtDate), Day(dtDate)) & ".dbf"

    ' check within folder on existence of file
    sFName = Dir(sPath & sDBF)
    If Len(sFName) > 0 Then

        ' open DBF file
        On Error Resume Next
        Set oWsSrc = Workbooks.Open(sPath & sFName).ActiveSheet
        If oWsSrc Is Nothing Then GoTo ERROR_DBF
        ' open destination workbook
        Set oWsDest = Workbooks.Open(sPath & cDestWorkBk).ActiveSheet
        On Error GoTo 0
        If oWsDest Is Nothing Then GoTo ERROR_PRICES

        ' determine range to be copied
        With oWsSrc.Cells.CurrentRegion
            Set raSrc = .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count)
        End With

        ' determine destination; first available row in column B
        Set raDest = oWsDest.Cells(oWsDest.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

        ' perform copy
        raSrc.Copy Destination:=raDest

        ' save prices.xlsx
        oWsDest.Parent.Save
        oWsDest.Parent.Close

        ' close DBF
        oWsSrc.Parent.Close SaveChanges:=False

    Else
        MsgBox "DBF file [" & sPath & sDBF & "] not found.", vbExclamation
    End If
    GoTo DONE

ERROR_DBF:
    MsgBox "Error opening DBF file " & sPath & sDBF, vbExclamation
    Exit Sub
ERROR_PRICES:
    MsgBox "Error opening workbook " & sPath & cDestWorkBk, vbExclamation
DONE:
End Sub
```

That works well for today, but I also have a data created each day for the following day, so I need to duplicate this macro, but have it look not for today's file, but for tomorrow's file. I tried simply making this change

```
' assign current date
    dtDate = Date + 1
```

but the macro still performs the task on today's data file.

Any thoughts on what requires changing to have the macro open tomorrows DBF file instead?

cheers

Comment: `dtDate = DateAdd("d", 1, Date)` maybe ? and for yesterday `dtDate = DateAdd("d", -1, Date)`. Or maybe try to make a simple userform with three buttons where each for yesterday, today and tomorrow.

Comment: Or input box, something like `dtDate = DateAdd("d", InputBox("when?"), Date)` where if input number -1 then it's yesterday, input number 0 then it's today, input number 1 then it's tomorrow, -2 the day before yesterday, 2 the day after tomorrow, and so on.

Comment: cheers Karma, but the macro is to be automated using a vb script, so no user input at all.  Thanks for your suggestion